# i have a question on the 'sorted()' in python

Tags: python

I know this is this right in the second line, but why the first line is not right? got this error:

```
def sort_stories_by_votes(hnlist):
    return sorted(hnlist, key= attrgetter(hnlist.votes), reverse=True)
    #return sorted(hnlist, key= lambda k:k['votes'], reverse=True)
```

i have the dict def like this

```
hn.append({'title': title, 'link': href, 'votes': points})
```

this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LabComputer\Downloads\scrape.py", line 35, in <module>
    pprint.pprint(create_custom_hn(mega_links, mega_subtext))
  File "C:\Users\LabComputer\Downloads\scrape.py", line 33, in create_custom_hn
    return sort_stories_by_votes(hn)
  File "C:\Users\LabComputer\Downloads\scrape.py", line 20, in sort_stories_by_votes
    return sorted(hnlist, key= attrgetter(hnlist.votes), reverse=True)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'votes'
```

Comment: hnlist is list of dicts and you can't access dict's member with dot operator.

Comment: You can access "votes" key in hnlist by htlist.get("votes")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error said, you are trying to access the attribute `votes` in `hnlist`, (i.e. `hnlist.votes`). Do this instead:

```
from operator import itemgetter

def sort_stories_by_votes(hnlist):
    return sorted(hnlist, key=itemgetter("votes"), reverse=True)
```

Note that [`operator.attrgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter) is meant to be used for accessing object's attributes, not for fetching values of a dictionary.